LED lights tripping the breaker when installed in the wrong direction?
I recently upgraded my light fixture from the old fluorescent tube lights to LEDs (2 socket fixture), and decide to lose the ballast also. After cutting the wires and rectifying the connections, I proceeded to connect the new LEDs. I tried it first with just one- the thing worked  and light was on. In the first one, I checked and installed the new LED correctly- with the neutral/live indication side of the lamp connected to the tombstone coming from the mains. It turns out that I screwed up with the 2nd LED I installed and put the side with the neutral/live indication on the opposite side . After turning on the power and as soon as I turned on the switch, the general circuit breaker tripped! When checking, I noticed that the plastic part above the connector in the tombstone where the second lamp was connected was slightly singed.
Questions
A) is it normal for the circuit breaker to trip if the LED was installed with the live/neutral side in the opposite tombstone/connector to the one where the mains connection is?
B) should I be worried about the tombstone being a little burnt? Even though it is now working well when installed with the live/neutral on the correct side? the inner plastic black ring was not burned.

What type of bulbs are you installing?  For instance, Type A is ballast compatible, Type B is ballast bypass, Type A+B can do both, and Type C has an external driver.  I had a Type A+B that started smoking when I installed it with the ballast...went with bypass for the rest.

I believe these florescent-replacement LEDs have the live and neutral terminals on one end and a short-circuit on the other end. This, combined with an "LED" dummy starter (which is also a short circuit), allows you to put the LED tube in either direction when the original dual-end wiring is retained.
Observe this wiring diagram (from Circuitstune.com):

If you short out the ballast and the starter (with a dummy), the LED tube I described allows the tube to be put in either way and the far-end completes the circuit.
The disadvantage of this type of tune is, as you discovered, is that if you wire just one tombstone and put the tube in backwards, you short out the power.
Since it's a dead short, the breaker should have tripped "instantly" so I doubt you did any damage.

LEDs are inherently polarized. But that is when they are running on direct current. You are connecting them to alternating current, so there is nothing to distinguish one direction from the other, and in fact the "LED" is really a complex mechanism including a driver circuit that handles changing from AC to DC and from 120V to a lower voltage.
In other words, you almost certainly miswired in a way that resulted in a simple short circuit (loose ground wire, nicked insulation on hot touching neutral or ground or metal case, etc.) and the problem most likely had nothing to do with hot vs. neutral per se. In reality, as I found in my old house, an awful lot of stuff can have hot and neutral reversed with no ill effects. There are certain situations where that can present a direct danger (exposed hot instead of exposed neutral) or lead to other problems. But most appliances, light fixtures, etc. really can't tell the difference between hot and neutral except by comparing to ground. And they shouldn't be comparing to ground if everything is working normally.
There is one possible exception: If a device has neutral and ground bonded and you swap hot and neutral coming into the device then when you turn it on you will get a short circuit. However, normally devices do not have neutral and ground bonded because that is only supposed to be done in the main breaker panel.
